# Preload data without object initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord, preloading

I'm preloading data using 'ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader'. The preloading takes about 5 seconds (11'000 records), even-tough the actual query takes about 0.2s the run.

I think this is because rails initiates an object for each record.
I don't need any relations of the object, just a few attributes.

This is the actual code:

```
pr = ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new
pr.preload(
    Car.all,
    {:models => :parts },
    Model.preload_parts(...)
)
```

preload_parts return a scope with some restrictions.

How can i get the preloader to just initiate hashes or maybe structs?

-e-

So here's what i want to do:

Get all cars of a user, load it's models and the parts for each model with restrictions on the models and parts. The purpose is to display all cars, models and parts.

Comment: But you need a few fields from all of these 11,000 records? How would loading them as a hash/struct help? Perhaps you should look at why you need to preload them?

Comment: I think it would be less time consuming to create hashes instead of ActiveRecord objects. My example code isn't quite right, because i'm not loading all cars, just a few. In the end i need the parts. By preloading them, i can reduce the number of queries.

Comment: You are looking for pluck method - it will override select part and will return an array of results (or hash depending on db) without instantiating AR objects. To get the right answer you will need to show us exactely what you want to  achieve.

Comment: i've updated the question